# How can I redirect all URLs subdomains to other URLs subdomains using Cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, reverse-proxy, amazon-cloudfront

I want to redirect a url and their subdomains `api.example.com/static/brands/*` to `www.example.com/brands/*`. My goal is that when a client go in `www.example.com/brands/*` the webpage seen is the webpage of `api.example.com/static/brands/*` but the URL is `www.example.com/brands/*` so it's totally transparent for him.

The domain name `api.example.com` is redirecting to an ALB.

I am a bit confused about what is the logic, how can I achieve this with Cloudfront?

Comment: Can you pls share your final code snippet? I'm working on a similar problem stastement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want is to make a cloudfront distrobution for `www.example.com`

Which has an origin `api.example.com/static/brands/`

and a pattern path `/brands/*` which redirects all requests from `example.com/brands/*` to the origin `api.example.com/static/brands/`

Answer (score 2):

You can use CloudFront Functions (lightweight JavaScript functions that execute at the edge). Here is an example reference of doing redirects based on country - you can modify based on your needs: https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudfront-functions/tree/main/redirect-based-on-country

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
What is the setup that I should configured in Cloudfront to do this?

Comment: In the CloudFront console, go to the Functions section and add your redirect function using the link above as a reference. You can then publish it and associate it to your distribution's cache behavior (essentially a route) — this tells CloudFront to execute the function on each request that matches that cache behavior.